# Validation subtracted UIn8 Swift

Tags: swift

How can I use an `if let` or some condition to know if a `UInt8` can be subtracted? For example, 40 - 0x32

```
if let test = 40 - 0x32{
}
```

Comment: `if 40 >= 0x32 { }`

Comment: @vacawama that should be an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any construct like this to test if you can perform a `Uint8` subtraction:

```
if let test = 40 - 0x32 { }
```

But you can transform it into a condition you can test.

You want to be sure that the subtraction does not go negative, so you'd like to check:

```
if 40 - 0x32 >= 0 { }
```

If one or both values are `UInt8` variables, even this will cause troubles because the subtraction will happen before you check if it is safe.

Instead, you can move the `0x32` to the other side of the equation by adding `0x32` to both sides giving:

```
if 40 >= 0x32 { }
```

This makes intuitive sense as well since your subtraction will not be negative if the first number is at least as large as the number being subtracted.

---

**Alternate Answer:**

Perform your calculation with `Int` and then test if the result fits into a `UInt8` using `UInt8(exactly:)`:

```
var a: UInt8 = 40
let result = Int(a) - Int(0x32)

if let answer = UInt8(exactly: result) {
    print("answer is \(answer)")
} else {
    print("result doesn't fit in a UInt8")
}
```

`UInt8(exactly:)` returns an `UInt8?` that is either wraps the value if it fits in a `UInt8` or is `nil` if the value is outside of the range of allowable values for a `UInt8`.

You could write it in one line which is then closer to your original try:

```
if let test = UInt8(exactly: 40 - 0x32) { }
```